# AppCompat toolbar's colorControlNormal is getting cached

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I'm working on migrating our preexisting Action Bar to a `Toolbar` and I've run into a slight issue.  Normally I want to have a navigation icon with a standard white back arrow.  However, in some cases, I want to change that arrow to gray.  To accomplish this, I do the following.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="?titlebarBackground"
    style="?actionBarStyle"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/action_bar_up_arrow"
    app:theme="?toolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

normally I set `?toolbarTheme` to just be `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`.  Then, in cases where I want to have a gray up arrow, I set the theme to be.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar.GrayControls">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gray</item>
</style>
```

This initially works flawlessly and my up arrow is changed to gray.  However, when I go back, that gray color is still persisted for the up arrows of all activities which were on the back stack.  If I open a new `Activity`, the arrow is changed to white, but any previous activities still have their arrow set to gray.

My question is twofold:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What's the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Drawables share a [ConstantState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState.html) when created from a resource and AppCompat uses [`setColorFilter`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/lollipop-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager.java#189-190) to backport tinting. So, when you open a new Activity, [TintManager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/lollipop-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager.java) sets a ColorFilter on the Drawable which updates all instances of that drawable.

> What's the best way to fix it?

If you want to make this drawable updatable without affecting other instances then you must mutate that existing constant state using `drawable.mutate()`

This should really be addressed in the library. **Edit:** [It has been fixed internally](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78289).

For a dirty fix, do this in onResume()

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
```

More info:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78289

http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()

Comment: One small addition to this: in order to make this work with the standard icon (R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha) I have to update the tint of the icon using TintManager.getDrawable() in `onRestart`.  I'm not a huge fan of that, given that TintManager is in the internal package; is there any way around that?

Comment: @Jonathan Check out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78289. Looks like it is fixed but not yet released.